# Java - printing values of HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

I have a simple program here which is meant to find all permutations of a set of letters, or a set of words. From what I can see the program does work in finding the number of permutations there are, however it will only print blank lines in place of where the possible permutations should be.
(Note, UI.println() works in every other case in printing outlines, but for some reason will not work here :( )

I included my method here which should do as I've described, as well as a method that should be able to print out the permutations.

Would anyone have any ideas on what I have done wrong here?

```
public class Permutations {

    public List<List<String>> findPermutations(Set<String> items){

        Set<String> copyOfItems = new HashSet<String>(items);   // a copy of the set of items that can be modified
        List<List<String>> ans = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // where we will collect the answer
        counter=0;
        //suggested approach:
        extendPermutation(copyOfItems, new Stack<String>(), ans);   

        return ans;
    }

   
    public void extendPermutation(Set<String> remainingItems, Stack<String> permutationSoFar, List<List<String>> allPermutations){
        /*# YOUR CODE HERE */
        Set<String> alternateSet = new HashSet<String>(remainingItems);
        if (remainingItems.isEmpty()) {
            allPermutations.add(permutationSoFar);
            this.counter = counter + 1;
        } 
        for (String str : remainingItems) {
            alternateSet.remove(str);
            permutationSoFar.push(str);
            extendPermutation(alternateSet,permutationSoFar,allPermutations);
            permutationSoFar.pop();
        }
    
        

    }

  
    public void setupGUI(){
        UI.addButton("A B C D E", ()->{printAll(findPermutations(Set.of("A","B","C","D","E")));});
        UI.addTextField("Letters", (String v)->{printAll(findPermutations(makeSetOfLetters(v)));});
        UI.addTextField("Words", (String v)->{printAll(findPermutations(makeSetOfWords(v)));});
        UI.addButton("Quit", UI::quit);
        UI.setDivider(1.0);
    }

    public void printAll(List<List<String>> permutations){
        UI.clearText();
        for (int i=0; i<permutations.size(); i++){
            for (String str : permutations.get(i)){UI.print(str+" ");}
            UI.println();
        }
        UI.println("----------------------");
        UI.printf("%d items:\n", permutations.get(0).size());
        UI.printf("%,d permutations:\n", counter);
        UI.println("----------------------");
    }

   
    public Set<String> makeSetOfLetters(String str){
        Set<String> ans = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            if (str.charAt(i)!=' '){
                ans.add(""+str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(ans);
    }

   
    public Set<String> makeSetOfWords(String str){
        Set<String> ans = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String v : str.split(" ")){ans.add(v);}
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(ans);
    }

    // Counter for the number of complete permutations found
    private long counter = 0;  

    
    public void reportCounter(){
        if ((counter<<54)==0) {UI.printMessage((counter>10000000)?((counter>>>20)+"M"):((counter>>>10)+"K"));}
    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Permutations p = new Permutations();
        p.setupGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't even compile. Probably you are seeing the result of an old compilation. Try to post all code.

Comment: Edited to contain all code, I figured I would only include relevant pieces!
 Hopefully that would be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
permutationSoFar.push(str);
extendPermutation(alternateSet, permutationSoFar, allPermutations);
permutationSoFar.pop();
```

You first add an item to the permutationSoFar,
then you add a refrence (not a deep copy) the permutationSoFar to your allPermutations, only to pop permutationSoFar. Making sure that your permutationSoFar never contains any elements.

When you print the list of permutationSoFars, the allPermutations, you print an list of empty lists.

Just glancing over your problem, this will likely solve the issue:

```
allPermutations.add(List.copyOf(permutationSoFar));
```

But, to be blunt, it is like the rest of your code, not the cleanest solution.